# Options to communicate to a C# desktop app from a linux server?

Tags: c#, client-server, real-time

The desktop application is being developed with a demo version that is supposed to run for a few minutes and after that would request the user to restart the application to run again **(the user has to input their login and password to access it)**, since I dont know much in this field the way I can think of doing this without the user bypassing it would be having a realtime communication between both or something of the sorts.

> After X minutes the server sends a
>   message to the client to close/disable
>   the client requiring the user to
>   restart it, it also limits the daily
>   usage on the demo for the same user.

**As I am very inexperienced in this type or communication I would like to consult you guys with what options I have here ?**

The desktop application is developed in c# to run mainly on windows OS as for the server we only have linux available and as to what sort of service, if it is possible to make a webapi or session in php or perl to work with it that would be reliable enough would be nice but if that is not possible we are open to hear other options.

**PS: If I have'nt given enough information or am missing anything important here please drop me a comment i will update as soon as possible.**

Comment: Your clients may use routers, firewalls etc, so I doubt you can send such request to all of them. You should better use timers in your application or ask server for time left to session end/daily limit via webservices or something like that.

Comment: @Silx I already thinked that far but that doesnt work out well, which is why we are looking for a better way to communicate to the client. As I don't know what are the most options I may have available I am looking for advices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd give a go to HTTPS with mutual certificate-based authentication as the safest option. The desktop app can poll the server (=ask periodically) and quit in case of no response / no connection / negative reponse.

However, based on the *type* of app you are developing and the *target audience*, you can expect an important amount of users to **have connectivity problems** or have **no connectivity at all**.

Because of this, at the end of the day, you can come up with a lot simpler solution, like measuring run-time locally without any server involved, and gain pretty much the same effect.

Comment: I am looking for a realtime communication here I have already tried checking the data from the client and it is not as reliable as we wish like i have said in comments in other replies.

Comment: @Prix HTTP(S) is probably the most permitted (read: by corporate firewalls) communication protocol you can find. If you think you can protect your software from being cracked by some client/server communication you are naive. If I can crack your software, I can remove any client/server communication without a) asking you for a permission, b) letting you to know.

Comment: I am sure that any one that thinks about protecting their software will not only thinking about communication as well as packing, obfuscating and all the sort. Take for example NCSoft not only they encrypt the communication they do from client to server as they as well protect the important part of their software ofc we all know nothing is 100% secure but we all do our parts to make it harder to break in. Which is why i am looking for a options to be able to communicate **from server to client** anytime I need to update any information or even disable the client using the server.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to involve a server to do this.

Just have the desktop application save the date and time when it started. Periodically on a timer you can check the current time, and see if too much time has elapsed for the demo version, and tell the user they have to quit.

It is very unlikely many users will try to get around this. They are more likely to dump your trial software in favour of something that treats them decently!

Comment: yes we need to go that far as I stated above mostly in regards to malicious users cracking it so having all the information handled server side is more secure, that is if we can manage a good way of communication between both. I have been searching for options and heard for example about mono with HttpChannel which seems to play nicely with firewall as I am still searching and dont have enough experience with this field I am here looking for option and advices from those who have.

Comment: Remoting (HttpChannel) is one of your options, but still you will crash on firewall/NAT (what I wrote above) you can read about best pratices here: http://www.thinktecture.com/resourcearchive/net-remoting-faq/remotingusecases

Comment: @Silx that is not currently one of my choices it is one way of doing it that I have saw while searching for options and I am still going to read about it, I was just mentioning it. My main option right now is to make a java server with SSL and Session to stablish the connection to the client, most because of compatibility to linux, with the possibility of a transparent connection from the client which will most likely skip routing etc. Since java is not my forth, I am looking for options.

Comment: You don't have many options here - it have to be either remoting or sockets communication. Of course WCF is a technology that overlays all interprocess communication ways, you may want to take a look at it but I have no idea about it' mono equivalent.

Answer (score -1):

Checking DateTime.Now could work as Ben stated, but you'd be better off with System.Timers.Timer. Set interval to be your desired interval between auth calls in milliseconds. Attach a handler to the elapsed event that asks for auth info. System.Timers.Timer works in a separate thread so you can take advantage of some parallelism here. Changing the system time shouldn't have any effect on System.Timers.Timer but I am not positive on that point.